# How does one change color of md-input-container line?

Tags: angular, material-design

I am building an angular4 application with input fields from the angular materials library (https://material.angular.io). I am only using Inputs from this library in my project. For this reason I don't want to bother with importing a whole custom theme for my basic needs. This seems overkill and plus I was having a difficult time to get it to work. What I want to do is just change the color of the line of the md-input-container. I would like it to be green when somebody clicks on the input and I would like it to be red if there is an invalid email address. How can I accomplish this? As of writing this, and all of today this particular section on the angular materials website is not working, so I have been unable to look at the documentation. In addition many similar questions on SO reference angularjs1. Any help solving this issue would be great!

Below is an image, now the line is purple, but I would like it to be green, and then red if an invalid email exists in the field.

This is what the html looks like

```
<md-input-container class="input-half-width" dividerColor="red">
  <input mdInput placeholder="E-postaddress" email>
  <!--<md-hint *ngIf="validateEmail(email.value)" align="end">Invalid email address</md-hint>-->
</md-input-container>
```

Is there some css I can add to make this work? If so how would it look?

[image]

Comment: How about `<md-error>`?

Comment: I guess theirs sass has needed constants.

Comment: Now the site is working, so I referred to this link (https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview) and got it to work. Still had a little bit of trouble getting it to work via copy and pasting the html/typescript. After I imported ReactiveFormsModule into app.module.ts. Then it worked nicely.